# What is the completed projective tensor product of compactly supported smooth functions on two manifolds?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products, smooth-functions

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds (not necessarily closed). It is a lovely fact that
$$C^\infty(M \times N) \cong C^\infty(M) \hat{\otimes}_\pi C^\infty(N).$$

See, for the instance, the book *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions, and Kernels* by Francois Trèves (Thm.51.6 on p.530). He also shows similar statements for distributions and compactly supported distributions.

Is it true or false that

$$C^\infty_c(M \times N) \cong C^\infty_c(M) \hat{\otimes}_\pi C^\infty_c(N)$$

and is there a convenient reference for this fact?

Comment: Could you please give me the page of Trèves's book where this is stated ?

Comment: See theorem 51.6, on page 530 of the Dover reissue. Note that he states the desired isomorphism for compactly supported functions when the manifolds are compact.

Comment: Thx for the page reference, will have a look at it and will come back to you

Comment: Afair, this is false already for $M=\mathbb R$. This was known by Grothendieck and might be the principal reason for the introduction of *inductive tensor products*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a smooth *compact* manifold. You can turn $C_{c}^\infty(X) $ into a *Fréchet* space by taking as family of semi-norms the suprema of the norms of all partial derivatives. If $X$ is not necessarily compact anymore but admits a countable sequence $K_n$ of compact subsets so that every compact subset of $X$ is contained in at least one $K_n$, then you can  still create, using similar method that what preceeds, a family of semi-norms on $C_{c}^\infty(X) $ turning it into a Fréchet space. Even more : In fact each smooth manifold $X$ of finite dimension can be made into such a increasing union of compact $K_n$. Then endow $X$ with a Riemannian metric $g$ which induces a distance $d(x, y)$, take an $x$ in $X$ (that I assume non empty !) and set $K_n = \{y\in X\;|\;d(x,y)\leq n\}$, and do what preceeds. All of this to say that in most reasonable cases, $C_{c}^\infty(X) $ can be turned into a Fréchet space for a family of semi-norms.

Suppose that $N$ and $M$ are reasonable enough so that $C_{c}^\infty(M) $ and $C_{c}^\infty(N) $ can be turned into Fréchet spaces for respective families $(p_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$ and $(q_{\beta})_{\beta\in J}$ of semi-norms as roughly describe previously. Fix a $(\alpha,\beta)\in I\times J$. Now, for a $\xi\in C_{c}^\infty(M) \otimes C_{c}^\infty(N)$, set $$\pi_{\alpha,\beta} (\xi)= \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^k p_{\alpha} (m_i) q_{\beta} (n_i) | \xi = \sum_{i=1}^k m_i \otimes n_i \}$$ You can then verify that $(\pi_{\alpha,\beta})_{(\alpha,\beta)\in I\times J}$ is a family of semi-norms on the tensor product $C_{c}^\infty(M) \otimes C_{c}^\infty(N)$. Now $C_{c}^\infty(M) \hat{\otimes}_\pi C_{c}^\infty(N)$ is just the completion of $C_{c}^\infty(M) \otimes C_{c}^\infty(N)$ for the previous family of semi-norms.

Now, thanks to the very construction of $C_{c}^\infty(M) \otimes C_{c}^\infty(N)$, you can show that you that it is sufficient to show the isomorphism $C_{c}^\infty(M \times N) \simeq C_{c}^\infty(M) \otimes C_{c}^\infty(N)$ locally, and then to glue. This allows you to suppose that $M$ and $N$ are open balls of some $\mathbf{R}^n$'s, and then you show the isomorphism explicitely.

Comment: If $M$ is not compact, the topology on $C^\infty_c(M)$ that I mean is not the Frechet topology inherited from all smooth functions. It is the topology arising as a colimit of the compactly supported smooth functions over an exhausting sequence of compact subsets of $M$. This topology is not Frechet; Treves uses the term ''LF topology'' and describes it in chapter 13, pages 131-133.

Comment: @user211769 Will have a look at this will proving the isomorphism, and then correct the answer, thx for the pages reference